# Boost.Python: How to expose a factory method to python

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I have a C++ API that is built into a dll, now I want to the api by python, so I decide to re-build the dll with boost.python, but I am new to boost.python.

The API is in file **CMyApi.h**, it has a factory method like this:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) CMyApi
{
public:
    static CMyApi* CreateUserApi(const char *path = "");

    virtual void Init() = 0;

protected:
    ~CMyApi(){};
};
```

CMyApi is a virtual class, and CApiImpl inherits from CMyApi, it is defined in **CApiImpl.h**:

```
class CApiImpl : public CMyApi
{
public:
    CApiImpi();
    ~CApiImpi();
    virtual void Init();
};
```

**CApiImpl.cpp** contains CApiImpl's implementation and the implementation of CMyApi::CreateUserApi:

```
static CMyApi* CMyApi::CreateUserApi(const char *path)
{
    return new CApiImpl();
}
```

I don't want to expose CApiImpl to api user, I'd like API to be called by CMyApi, so what user have are CMyApi.h and a DLL file.

CMyApi is wrapped like this:

```
class CMyApiWrapper : public CMyApi, public wrapper<CMApi>
{
    void Init()
    {
        this->get_override("Init")();
    }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(CMyApiWrapper)
{
    class_<CMyApiWrapper>("CMyApiWrapper")
        .def("CreateUserApi", &CMyApi::CreateUserApi)
        .staticmethod("CreateUserApi")
        .def("Init", pure_virtual(&CMyApi::Init));
}
```

The above BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE can't pass build, what's wrong in my program?

Comment: Any error message for that can' t pass build?

Comment: What is the desired ownership semantics for objects returned by `CMyApi::CreateUserApi()`?  How does one delete the returned object with the protected destructor?  Can you provide an example on how `CMyApiWrapper` would be constructed and used from within Python?